# Building iOS app on Jenkins slave returns error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, cocoapods, jenkins-agent

I've ran into a problem with configuring Jenkins slave for building iOS app. I have set everything as described in [this](https://blog.samsao.co/how-to-setup-a-jenkins-slave-running-mac-os-x-for-ios-projects-part-1-2937502ce90b#.nladebjqt) tutorial, but every time my build fails with message:

```
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
 
** BUILD FAILED **
 
The following build commands failed:
 
`PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock
/PATH_TO_PROJECT/Build/Intermediates/xxxx.build/Release-iphoneos/xxxx.build/Script-F0C04920AA373F4352DB3101.sh`
 
(1 failure) Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure Finished:
FAILURE
```

Version of `cocoapods` is `1.1.1`

`xCode` version `7.3.1`

I use mac mini as slave device (Sierra OS X)

I have run pod install via terminal and build works fine from xCode.

I'll be available for all additional questions, and will appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
For some reason plugin "CocoaPods Jenkins Integration" doesn't work well so Podfile.lock and Manifest.lock were different and because of that project couldn't build.

Comment: Don't just say your problem is solved. Write the solution here